# Windows backup is unable to start error 0x80070057

Tags: windows-7, windows-backup

I'm unable to start Windows backup. It failes with error: 0x80070057

Any solution for this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

run `cmd` as Administrator, type:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\System /v CopyFileBufferedSynchronousIo /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f
```

Reboot.

way 2:

run `cmd` as Administrator, type:

```
fsutil usn queryjournal C:
fsutil usn deletejournal /D C:
```

Reboot.

Comment: Does not help...

Comment: @Spacedust Disk name, when need backup?

Comment: I'm trying to backup disk C:

Comment: @Spacedust Test way 2?

Comment: I've tested both, rebooted, still the same :/

Comment: @Spacedust http://us.norton.com/downloads-trial-norton-utilities use Disk Doctor

Comment: Does not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Follow both KB Articles from Microsoft, they deal with Backup issues with error

**"0x80070057" error message when you back up files in Windows 7**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982736/

Do the change of the decimal symbol setting in control panel.

*To change the decimal symbol setting, follow these steps:*

> - Open Control Panel, click Clock, Language, and Region, and then click Region and Language.
> - Click the Formats tab, and then click Additional settings.
> - In the Decimal symbol field, type . (dot), and then click OK two times.
> - Restart the computer.

**Restore operation by using Backup and Restore may fail in Windows 7 SP1 or in Windows Server 
2008 R2 SP1**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2569601/

Comment: It says that this update is not needed on this computer...

Comment: try the steps from the first KB in this case and change the language settings

Comment: It didn't help and also caused problems with Word 2003

Answer (score 0):

Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly by using Registry Editor or by using another method.If you are not sure about making changes to registry, [get the fix it for me program here.](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9777176)

1. Click **Start** button, type **Regedit.exe** in the Search programs and files box, and then press ENTER.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\System**
3. On the **Edit** menu, point to **New**, and then click **DWORD Value**.
4. Type **CopyFileBufferedSynchronousIo**, and then press ENTER.
5. Right-click CopyFileBufferedSynchronousIo, and then click Modify.
6. In the Value data box, type **1**, and then click OK.
7. Exit Registry Editor.